# Simple Invoice add in QuickBooks using vb.net and QuickBooks 2015

Tags: vb.net, quickbooks

When I try to add invoices into QuickBooks I get the response.staus as "Status OK" but I can't see the values in QuickBooks.

```
Dim customerRet As ICustomerRet = customerRetList.GetAt(i)
                CustomerName = customerRet.Name.GetValue()
                QuickBooksID = customerRet.ListID.GetValue()
                requestMsgSet = sessionManager.CreateMsgSetRequest("US", 13, 0)
                requestMsgSet.Attributes.OnError = ENRqOnError.roeContinue
                Dim invoiceAddRq As IInvoiceAdd = requestMsgSet.AppendInvoiceAddRq()
                invoiceAddRq.CustomerRef.ListID.SetValue(customerRet.ListID.GetValue())
               invoiceAddRq.CustomerRef.FullName.SetValue(customerRet.FullName.GetValue())
                invoiceAddRq.RefNumber.SetValue(15)
                ' Add these lines to your request
                Dim invoiceLineAdd As IORInvoiceLineAdd = invoiceAddRq.ORInvoiceLineAddList.Append()

                invoiceLineAdd.InvoiceLineAdd.ItemRef.FullName.SetValue("Sales")
                ' invoiceLineAdd.InvoiceLineAdd.Amount.SetValue(1000)
                invoiceLineAdd.InvoiceLineAdd.Desc.SetValue("Test")
                invoiceLineAdd.InvoiceLineAdd.Quantity.SetValue(Convert.ToDouble(1))
                invoiceLineAdd.InvoiceLineAdd.ORRatePriceLevel.Rate.SetValue(Convert.ToDouble(10))
              invoiceLineAdd.InvoiceLineAdd.Amount.SetValue(Convert.ToDouble(1005))
                invoiceLineAdd.InvoiceLineAdd.ServiceDate.SetValue(DateTime.Now)
                Dim invoiceResponseMsgSet As IMsgSetResponse = sessionManager.DoRequests(requestMsgSet)
                Dim invoiceResponse As IResponse = invoiceResponseMsgSet.ResponseList.GetAt(0)
                Dim invoiceRet As IInvoiceRet = DirectCast(invoiceResponse.Detail, IInvoiceRet)

                Dim StatusMessage As String = response.StatusMessage
                Dim statusCode As Integer = response.StatusCode
```

Answer (score 0):

When you say that you can't find it in QuickBooks, how are you searching for it? There's a couple of lines that stand out as being redundant or odd.

```
invoiceLineAdd.InvoiceLineAdd.Quantity.SetValue(Convert.ToDouble(1))
invoiceLineAdd.InvoiceLineAdd.ORRatePriceLevel.Rate.SetValue(Convert.ToDouble(10))
invoiceLineAdd.InvoiceLineAdd.Amount.SetValue(Convert.ToDouble(1005))
```

QuickBooks will calculate the Amount if you enter the Quantity and Rate, or will calculate the Rate if you enter the Quantity and Amount. I'm not sure what you're invoice would look like as you have a Quantity of 1, a Rate of 10 (totaling $10.00), and a Amount of $1005 (which would be a Rate of $1005).

You're not setting the Transaction Date for the invoice. There's a setting in QuickBooks to use either Today's date as the default, or the last used transaction date, so it may be that the invoice is being put under a different date than expected.

It also appears that your RefNum value is a number, but should be a string. I don't know if VB will automatically change that for you.

If you get a Status OK response, check the returned values to see if they match what you sent. I would also suggest doing a search